# How to round up the number to tens (always up)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I come to you with a problem that I have spent almost two days on and I still cannot find a solution. I have a task that concerns mathematical calculations. I have a rule that you should always round the result up to tens (always up to the top). Examples: the result is 1 must be rounded to 10, the result is 2 must be rounded to 10, the result is 10, the result is 10, the result is 11 must be rounded to 20, the result is 99 must be rounded to 100, and so on. All of my example i tested at this [page.](https://www.w3schools.com/SQl/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_isnumeric)

I know that we have three 'basic' functions for rounding. The first is the ceiling, which I would be interested in, but the ceiling does not always work the way I want it to. For example, for int value it is always this number, if it is 90 it will return 90, if it is 17 it will return 17 and so on. Code for this situation is below.

```
SELECT CEILING(91)
```

We also have a function that is used for rounding, but I cannot find the right parameters that will allow me to round a number up always. The positive maximum number is 1 and the rest of the z-directs my values. For example for 91 it will return 90 (with -1 param) and for 96 it will be 100 (with -1 param) but i want this 91 become 100.

```
SELECT ROUND(91, -1)
```

Thus, I wanted to try to do something with the floor, even doing some mathematical calculations, but in the long term, there are some mistakes. It will be work fork 91 (return 100) but for 90 it is still 100, when it should be 90.

```
SELECT FLOOR(90/10) * 10 + 10 AS RoundValue
```

Does anyone have any indication of how I could do this? Unfortunately, the compiler I use does not allow me to use the IF syntax at the beginning, the query must always start with select.

Comment: Isn't `CEILING(91/10) * 10` what you want?

Comment: If you need exactly integer, then look for some function like `CAST` or `CONVERT`, the exact syntax of whose is DBMS dependent

Comment: @AlexLarionov this ceiling dosen`t work because ofc for 91 it will be work, but for 90 it`s still 100 but shoud be 90. How to avoid it?

Comment: @JakubBidziński `CEILING(90/10) * 10` returns 90.

Comment: @forpas

Perhaps I asked the wrong question. In a situation where the outcome is:
1. 91 the system is to show 100.
2. 90 the system is to show 90.
3. 92 system is supposed to show 100.
4. 99 the system is supposed to show 100.

The case is rounded but down. I need to round up!

Comment: @JakubBidziński obviously you are using a database that performs integer division when the operands are integers. So 91/10 returns 9 and not 9.1. This is why it is important to tag your question with that specific database, like SQL Server.

Comment: @forpas Yea, i will do it next time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CEILING()` looks like the right approach, but we need to work around integer division. This would seem to do what you want:

```
select val, ceiling(val / 10.0) * 10 as roundvalue
from (values (1), (10), (15), (90), (91), (95), (99)) t(val)
```

**[Yields](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f2c2e8594df32b43dc4789c499964f3d)**:

```
val | roundvalue
--: | ---------:
  1 |         10
 10 |         10
 15 |         20
 90 |         90
 91 |        100
 95 |        100
 99 |        100
```

Comment: Perhaps I asked the wrong question. In a situation where the outcome is:
1. 91 the system is to show 100.
2. 90 the system is to show 90.
3. 92 system is supposed to show 100.
4. 99 the system is supposed to show 100.

The case is rounded but down. I need to round up!

Answer (score 2):

You can tweak the `round` function to get the desired value as follows:

```
select  round(val+4, -1) as roundvalue
from (values (1), (10), (15), (90), (91), (95), (99)) t(val)
```

[DB<>Fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9a8bfb7c0c6c0e4c7e2d6c3bd222c2e9)